# Connect to a vpn through tor nftables

Tags: socks, openvpn, firewall, iptables

I have a box with 3 interfaces wlan0, eth0 (with internet connection) and tun0 (Openvpn). I want to connect that box to a remote vpn using tor socks. Until now I have the sock 60140 open in tor, the openvpn client set to use 60140 but Im missing on what iptables/nftables rules do I have to set in order to redirect al the tun0 traffic over that 60140 Sock.

The scheme I need to acomplish is this:

(Box tun0) -> Tor -> Vpn

I also need info on routing tables if needed. Thanks.

Comment: are you aware of, that your setup probably makes no sense regarding of anonymity?

Comment: Well, if the vpn traffic is encapsulated through TOR then you cant see what vpn you are connected to from the local network.

Comment: yes, the only result is, that you perhaps anonymize your connection to the VPN... but who is running the VPN-server? **||** you? (this would make anonymization pointless.) **||** some 3rd party? (how well do you know them? you may have other known connections to them. - how well do they know you? they can probably still identify your traffic with their knowledge about you.) **||** is it a "usual" VPN-provider? (how are you paying their bill? no, bitcoin are **NOT** anonymous, just pseudonym.)

Comment: although it's not your question, but has some good information about VPNs in conjunction with Tor: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#IsTorLikeAVPN

Comment: @DJCrashdummy it's not a "normal" escenario... and yes, the only thing im looking for is to anonimize the connection inside the box's network. The endpoint is free btw.